# Python command on MacOS terminal not working

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, terminal

I am using MacOS 10.8. I uninstalled python 3.2.3 and installed 2.7. 
But when I type `python` in the terminal it shows:

```
-bash: python3: command not found.
```

if I use `/usr/bin/python` then python 2.7 runs. How do I fix this?

Comment: Doesn't 2.7 already come with OS X?

Comment: type in `which python` and see where it points.  The fact that typing in `python` gives a bash message about `python3` not being found is a little fishy.  You may have an alias set.  to check, type `alias -p` or `alias -p | grep python` to find aliases which are only related to python.

Comment: got this output.
alias python='python3'
how to correct this?

Comment: you probably set that alias in your .profile file (check for ~/.profile). if so, remove that line (or comment it, for future)

Comment: cant access the .profile file

Comment: try `.bash_profile` or every other `.` file that has `profile` or `rc` in it.  you might have set it in one of those.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake. First save your python file in a folder, and make sure that you have a .py at the end. Then go to terminal, and type in the address without adding users. For example, my .py file is saved in a folder named Python, on my desktop. My python file is called read. It will work:)

python ~/Desktop/Python/read.py

Then click enter in terminal, and your file should execute.

Answer (score -1):

Check if /usr/bin/ is in your PATH variable.

```
echo $PATH
```

on the commandline.

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin.
got this output.

Comment: See the comment by Samuele Mattiuzzo, that should be your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You might have python3 symlinked to python. If thats the case then just make sure all file names containing python3 in your /usr/bin/ have been deleted.